# Change Value in ObjectAnimator of AnimatorSet programmatically

Tags: java, android, objectanimator, animatorset

I'd like to change a value of an `ObjectAnimator` which is part of an `AnimatorSet`, which is coded in Xml in a designated file in the animator directory.

I don't want to replace the Xml file with Java code, neither do I want to split it up.

Is it possible?

example code:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="1.0"
        android:valueTo="0.0"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:duration="0" />

    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="-170"  <!-- I want to change this value on run time -->
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:propertyName="rotationY"
        android:duration="@integer/anim_length" />

    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="0.0"
        android:valueTo="1.0"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:startOffset="@integer/anim_length_half"
        android:duration="0" />

</set>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible.

```
    AnimatorSet animatorSet = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this, R.animator.anim_yours);

    List<Animator> animators = animatorSet.getChildAnimations();
    for (int i = 0; i < animators.size(); i++) {
        Animator animator = animators.get(i);
        if (animator instanceof ObjectAnimator) {
            ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = (ObjectAnimator) animator;
            if ("rotationY".equals(objectAnimator.getPropertyName())) {
                float fromValue = -100;
                float toValue = 0;
                objectAnimator.setFloatValues(fromValue, toValue);
            }
        }
    }
    // and you use changed AnimoatorSet..
```

Comment: After that, how do you use animatorSet on view or AnimatedVectorDrawable ?